# Fancybox overlay not expanding to height

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Using the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.4,
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#FFF'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However the height of the background on the overlay is staying at 0. [Click here to see](http://lewesestates.propertylogic.net/index.php?option=com_propertysearch&view=full_details_adv_ricky&p_department=RS&propertyID=473658&Itemid=97)

Comment: Seems fine to me I think. You only have a very light background colour on the fancybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of your fancybox **js** file is `2.0.6` but your fancybox **css** file is for `v2.0.5`. Upgrade your fancybox css file to v2.0.6 and problem solved.